# Replace a few characters in a string literal using C++

Tags: c++

i have

```
cost char* a="test_r.txt"
```

i want to strip the _r and add _n instead of it so that it becomes "test_n.txt" 
 and save it in const char* b;

what is the easiest way to do it ?

Comment: Use `std::string`. You can't modify the contents of string literals.

Comment: i am using a library that gives me const char* .

Comment: Which is implicitly convertible to a string, and can easily be changed back.

Comment: Same question in C [c - Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a "char *s" initialized with a string literal, but not "char s[]"? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-char-s-initialized-with-a)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly modify the contents of `a`, so you'll need some copying:

```
std::string aux = a;
aux[5] = 'n';
const char* b = aux.c_str();
```

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned before, if you put your `const char *` into a `std::string`, you can change your characters. Regarding the replacing of a constant that is longer than one character you can use the `find` method of `std::string`:

```
const char *a =  "test_r_or_anything_without_r.txt";

std::string a_copy(a); 
std::string searching("_r");
std::string replacing("_n");
size_t pos_r = 0;

while (std::string::npos != (pos_r = a_copy.find(searching, pos_r)))
{
    a_copy.replace(a_copy.begin() + pos_r,
                   a_copy.begin() + pos_r + searching.length(),
                   replacing.begin(), replacing.end());
}

const char *b = a_copy.c_str();
```